# Why Do I need an Assignment Operator in This Statement?

Tags: php

I'm playing around with some different design patterns to teach myself more about them, and started using DI Containers.

### Main Code (index.php)

```
$container = new \League\Container\Container();

$container->add("config", function(){
    return new Config(APP_ROOT . "/config.json");
});


$container->add("GoogleBooks", GoogleBooksProvider::class)
    ->withArgument( $container['config'] );


$container->add("books", BookRepository::class);

// empty array, as expected
var_dump($container['books']->getProviders());

// this line doesn't add the provider
$container['books']->addProvider( $container['GoogleBooks'] );

// empty array, should expect to have one entry, GoogleBooksProvider
var_dump($container['books']->getProviders());
```

### BookRepository::addProvider

```
public function addProvider( iProvider $provider ) {
    $this->_providers->push($provider);

    return $this;
}
```

That doesn't work as expected, problem described in the code comments. However, if I swap

```
$container['books']->addProvider( $container['GoogleBooks'] );
```

with

```
$container['books'] = $container['books']->addProvider( $container['GoogleBooks'] );
```

it works correctly, by storing the GoogleBooksProvider in the BookRepository. Why do I need an assignment operator to make that work correctly?

If I do it without putting it in the container, it works as I expected, without the assignment operator.

```
$br = new BookRepository();

$br->addProvider( new GoogleBooksProvider($container['config']) );

// shows GoogleBooks is in the _providers array
var_dump($br->getProviders());
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are *adding*, but not *sharing* the service, you fetch a *new* instance of `BookRepository` every time you access the container:

```
var_dump($container['books'] === $container['books']); // false
```

If you want to share `BookRepository`, you need to use this:

```
$container->add("books", BookRepository::class, true);
```

or (shorter)

```
$container->singleton("books", BookRepository::class);
```